# odoo 16 enable fullcalender vertical resource view

Tags: odoo, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, odoo-16, fullcalendar-6

I try to enable vertical resource view in Odoo 16 calendar.

I did:

```bash
npm install --save @fullcalendar/core  @fullcalendar/resource @fullcalendar/resource-timegrid`
```

and put an import statement in web/static/src/views/calendar/hooks.js like

```js
async function loadJsFiles() {
const files = \[
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/core/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/interaction/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/luxon/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/list/main.js",
"/web/static/lib/fullcalendar/node_modules/@fullcalendar/resource-daygrid/index.js",
\];

for (const file of files) {
await loadJS(file);
}
}
```

When I run this, I always get

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know what is wrong or can anyone explain how to implement fullcalender vertical resource view in Odoo 16? I know that I have to call the resource plugin with options in "web/static/src/views/calendar/calendar_common/calendar_common_renderer.js", but at the moment I can't even load the js file.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

sorry, i just saw that odoo 16 comes with fullcalendar 4.4.0.
i did  `npm install --save @fullcalendar/core  @fullcalendar/resource @fullcalendar/resource-timegrid`
`
and fullcalendar premium 6.x.x was installed.

So it could not work.
now i have another problem:
the daily resources are displayed correctly but i can see now time values or a grid

Answer (score 0):

finally i got it working, except the default view.
its always the week view that shows at first.

i initiate the views in /web/static/src/views/calendar/calendar_common/calendar_common_renderer.js

```
const SCALE_TO_FC_VIEW = {
    day: "resourceTimeGridDay",
    week: "timeGridWeek",
    month: "dayGridMonth",
};

and in get options:
........
defaultView: SCALE_TO_FC_VIEW[this.props.model.scale],
```

but i cant get the day view set to default.
i tried initilView as well.
does anyone know how to do it?